# Admin Panel for Laravel + Angular

Tags: angular, laravel

Now I'm building web project using Laravel (API) + Angular.
And I need to add admin panel on my project now.
I'm thinking 2 ways to do this.

1. Admin Panel in Laravel
2. Admin Panel in Angular

Which is the recommended way to add Admin panel in my project?
And Why?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the way you want. If you have more experience with Angular, then there will be easier for you using that framework, if not, if you want to render the views and data directly from the server, you use Laravel directly isntead.

IMHO, doing it directly with Laravel is a little bit easier but you face some limitations, ok no limitations but to achieve more complex things or behaviors it will be easier to do it with Angular or Vue, with those tools you have special components and a lot of resources on the web. At the end of the day, all will be reduced to the complexity of the Admin that you want to build and to your experience withe the tools mencioned above.

As I said, **this is just my opinion**.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages that give you admin panel in laravel out of the box, I've never used them but a quick google search did show some promising results like [Laravel-admin](https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin), [QuickAdmin](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/quickadmin)

You can also do it in Angular, but you'd also need to:

1. build your own UI
2. authorise requests on server-side (Passport)

bright side is you can admin whatever you want with your custom built solution, also somewhat easier to make it into a mobile app if that's even relevant :)